# Need help to find a strategy for repo (tool)

Tags: android, git, branch, repository

I'm working on a froyo image for a multimedia set top box. The original image comes with a customized mplayer, which has hardware support for SoC. The Android multimedia frameworks (audio/video) are completely bypassed and all playback is done with this mplayer. To make it even worse, mplayer is compiled with OSS instead of ALSA. My medium term goal is, to integrate alsa with dmix support in the android platform and compile mplayer with alsa support, so that both android and mplayer can play concurrently.

In the meantime I want to change smaller things on the original image (mostly UI,UX). So I'm thinking of having two branches. One for the original and slightly improved image and one for the bigger alsa changes. The alsa branch would have some other git repositories than the original one, for example the alsa stuff. Furthermore some git projects might need to have its own branch for the alsa implementation (mplayer for alsa output, bionic for shared memory, etc.).
So, to switch between the original branch and the alsa branch, I had to switch the branch of some git repositories and there would be some repositories, which are exclusive for the alsa branch.

Can I achieve this with repo? Is this just a matter of starting a alsa topic branch with repo?

Could you please describe, how you would setup the android platform for this? Any hints are appreciated.

Cheers,
Henrik

P.S. Does it make sense to define two different products for this scenario?

P.P.S. I already asked this question in the android-porting google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-porting/K0JmK9HFAVw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like feature implementation on the same product, rather than different products.

If all necessary gits are in place on all branches you just need to point the affected gits to the correct branch for your ALSA feature. This could be done e.g. by adding a `local_manifest.xml` in the `.repo` directory, which would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
<remove-project name="platform/blah"/>
<project path="blah"
    name="platform/blah"
    revision="alsa-feature-branch"/>
</manifest>
```

You'd then re-sync your repo and start topic branches in the gits that you need to make changes in.

There's also the possibility of merging the changes back to your main branch once the feature is done (or even doing the feature development directly on the main branch), and having a flag in your product makefile or `system.prop` file that decides whether the feature will be used or not.

Comment: So, if I wanted to work on the ALSA branch, I had to copy the local_manifest in place and run repo sync. If I than wanted to switch back to the master branch, I would have to rename the local_manifest, so that repo does not find it and run repo sync again? Is that the workflow? Seems a little bit complicated to me ;)

Comment: Do you expect to switch back and forth often? In that case you could sync 2 copies of the repo, and only alter the manifest in one of them. That's what I usually do.

Comment: Yes, because I probably want to merge the changes of the master branch into the ALSA branch. I could branch the manifest repository to have one master manifest and one ALSA manifest. Locally I would have two complete project copies. One for master and one for ALSA. Is that, what you are suggesting?

Comment: That's what I do if there are multiple gits that are branched out. I init/sync two repos and alter the manifest for one of them. If I need some changes from the main branch on my feature branch I can do a `git merge --no-ff`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think of having two repos, but that seams to be a feasible solution. Thanks Michael.